# at its core VS to the core

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

1. **Google is a search engine to the core.**
2. **Google is a search engine at its core.**

Is there any difference between those sentences?

Comment: To the core: Google's nature is to  be a search engine and that is completely what it is. At the core: Google is more than one thing but being a search engine is its central role.

Comment: John is an honest man to the core - he is completely honest in every way. MacDonalds serves many foods but at its core it is a burger company.